# Total Differentials

Tags: derivatives

I was studying for some quizzes when I stumbled on this question:

> The specific gravity of a body is given by the formula $s = \frac{A}{A-W}$ where $A$ is the weight in air and $W$ the weight in water. If, for a certain body, $A = 16 $ pounds and $W = 8$ pounds, and each of these values may be in error by $0.01 $ pounds, what is approximately the greatest possible error in the computed value of $s$ ?

My work:

I do know that the total differential of $z $ is:
$$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} dx +\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} dy$$

In the problem above, I need to find the total differential of $s$. I believe it look like this:

$$ds = \frac{\partial s}{\partial A} dA +\frac{\partial s}{\partial W} dy$$

Now getting the $\frac{\partial s}{\partial A}$ :
$$\frac{\partial s}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial}{\partial A} \left (\frac{A}{A-W} \right ) = \frac{-W}{(A - W)^2}$$

Now getting the $\frac{\partial s}{\partial W}$ :
$$\frac{\partial s}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial}{\partial W} \left (\frac{A}{A-W} \right ) = \frac{A}{(A - W)^2}$$

Then: $$ds = \frac{-W}{(A - W)^2} dA + \frac{A}{(A - W)^2} dW$$

I remember that $A = 16$ pounds, $W = 8$ pounds and the error is $dA = dW = 0.01$ pounds. Substituting these values to the preceding equation:

$$ds = \frac{-(8)}{(16 - 8)^2} (0.01) + \frac{16}{(16 - 8)^2} (0.01)$$

Giving out the greatest possible error in computing the value of $s$ to be $ds = 0.00125$.

The answer given in my book is $ds = 0.00375.$ How would I get the value of $ds = 0.00375.$?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Answer (score 1):

You don't know that $dA=0.01$ and $dW=0.01$.

Rather, $dA=\pm0.01$, and likewise for $dW$. Trying the various possibilities gives a maximum $|ds|$ of what you say it should be.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.......maybe there's error in my equation or logic?

Comment: @Palautot Ka: the problem statement ("each of these values may be in error by 0.01 pounds") does **not** imply that $dA=0.01$. It implies only that $|dA|=0.01$. An error might be too high *or* too low. So the error is in your logic, not your derivation of the expression for $ds$.

Comment: So if $ds = \frac{-W}{(A - W)^2} dA + \frac{A}{(A - W)^2} dW$......how would I insert $|dA|=0.01$ into the equation? ...

Comment: ...... okay, now you're just not thinking. $dA$ may be *either* $0.01$ *or* $-0.01$. **Try them both** (along with both options for $dW$) to find the greatest value of $|ds|$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need calculus for this - just find the smallest possible measurement for the numerator, and divide by the largest possible measurement of the denominator

$$\frac{16-0.01}{(16-0.01)-(8+0.01)} = 2.003759$$

Comment: I agree, but I want to use the total differentials to remember and familiarize it more......